# How to tell varnish to cache specific file types

Tags: vcl, varnish

I have a dedicated server that host my own websites. I have installed varnish with the default VCL file. Now I want to tell varnish to do the following:

1. Cache only the following static file types (.js, .css, .jpg, .png, .gif, .jpg). Those are the server file types that are served, not URLs ended with the those extensions.
2. Do not cache files that are bigger than over 1M byte
3. Caching of any file should expire in 1 day (or whatever period).
4. Caching may happen only when Apache send 200 HTTP code.

Otherwise leave the request intact so it would be served by Apache or whatever backend.

What should I write in the VCL file to achieve those requirements ? Or what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did :

1- Isolate all static contents to another domain  (i.e. domain to serve the dynamic pages is different from the domain the serve static contents.)

2- Assign another dedicated IP Address to the domain that serve static contents

3- Tell varnish to only listen to that IP (i.e. static contents IP) on port 80

4-  Using Apache conf to control caching period to each static content type (varnish will just obey that headers)

cons:

1- Varnish will not even listen or process to the requests that it should leave intact. Those requests (for dynamic pages) are going directly to Apache since Apache listen to the original IP (performance).

2- No need to change default VCL default file (only if you want to debug) and that is helpful for those who don't know the principles of VCL language.

3- You are controlling everything from Apache conf.

Pros:

1- You have to buy a new dedicated IP if you don't have a spare one.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do all of this in the vcl_fetch subroutine. This should be considered pseudocode.

```
if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text/javascript|text/css|image/.*") {
    if (std.integer(beresp.http.Content-Length,0) < /* max size in bytes here */ ) {
        if (beresp.status == 200) { /*  backend returned 200 */
            set obj.ttl = 86400; /* cache for one day */
            return (deliver);
        }
    }
} 
set obj.ttl = 120;
return (hit_for_pass); /* won't be cached */
```